# Некорректное кодирование символов кириллицы функцией BindValue

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, symfony3

Есть необходимость работать с MS SQL 2008 R2
Для возможности разработки развернул всё необходимое ПО:

1. Ubuntu 16

   1. Apache 2
   2. PHP 7
   3. Symfony 3.0 (c leaseweb/doctrine-pdo-dblib)
2. Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

   1. MS SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 (локаль Cyrillic_General_CI_AS - менять нельзя)

Имеется контроллер, содержащий SQL запрос

```php
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$sql="
select
    isnull(ID,'') as 'id'
    ,isnull(SNAME,'') as 'sname'
    ,isnull(FNAME,'') as 'fname'
from TBL1
where SNAME like '%'+:sname+'%' ";

$sql =  iconv('UTF-8','Windows-1251', $sql);
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':sname', iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1251', $request->request->get('sname')), 'text');
$statement->execute();
```

Но при просмотре запроса через SQL Server Profiler видим, что вместо, например, строки  `Иванов` формируется `0xc8e2e0edeee2`, т.е. символы кириллицы переводятся в их коды (причём коды UTF8).

Если не использовать перекодировку, а просто написать

```php
$statement->bindValue(':sname', $request->request->get('sname'), 'text');
```

В SQL Server Profiler увидим `0xd098d0b2d0b0d0bdd0bed0b2`.

Если же делать вставку переменной напрямую

```php
$sname = $request->request->get('sname');
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$sql="
select
    isnull(ID,'') as 'id'
    ,isnull(SNAME,'') as 'sname'
    ,isnull(FNAME,'') as 'fname'
from TBL1
where SNAME like '%'+'".$sname."'+'%' ";

$sql =  iconv('UTF-8','Windows-1251', $sql);
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
```

То SQL Server Profiler видим корректную строку `Иванов`.

---

Если передавать строки в латинице, то никаких проблем не наблюдается:
передали `Ivanov` и получили `Ivanov`. Причём как надо: в одинарных кавычках.

---

**В чём может быть проблема?**

Comment: Порывшись на всевозможных форумах, пришёл к выводу, что проблема из-за php7.

Но ещё попробую исправить сам

Answer (score 1):

Для корректной работы необходимо установить локаль `ru_RU.CP1251`.

Плюс скорректировать код:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$sql="
select
    isnull(ID,'') as 'id'
    ,isnull(SNAME,'') as 'sname'
    ,isnull(FNAME,'') as 'fname'
from TBL1
where SNAME like :sname";

$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':sname', "%{$request->get('sname')}%", 'text');
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: Локаль где установить? Из примера не понятно.  
  
И править код не нужно, т.к. приведён лишь фрагмент. В полном варианте всё корректно.

Comment: локаль установить в системе на которой установлен php.

Comment: Русифицировать консоль Ubuntu?
Напиши команды, которые предлагаешь выполнить, чтобы было понятно без терминов.

Comment: Посмотреть какие локали установлены можно командой `locale -a`. Команда для установки локали ru_RU.cp1251: `sudo localedef -c -i ru_RU -f CP1251 ru_RU.CP1251`.

Comment: Что такое локаль можно прочитать на википедии - [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Локаль](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C)

Comment: Такая настройка никакого эффекта не дала

Comment: Странно. Я недавно обновился на ubuntu 16.04 и была похожая проблема, но после установки локали она решилась. Конфигурация у меня практически такая же, только Sql Server 2012 и ещё я использую freetds при подключении.

Comment: Freetds тоже есть, т.к. без него не работает в принципе. Но подключение происходит через `leaseweb/doctrine-pdo-dblib`. Возможно у нас не тлько версии SQL Server различаются. Да и, ка кбыл сказано, ситуация была `подобная`

Comment: Нашёл ещё одно различие без которого у меня вновь возникает такая проблема. Необходимо в настройках базы поставить в `true` параметры `ANSI_NULLS Enabled, ANSI_PADDING Enabled, ANSI_WARNINGS Enabled, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`. Это можно сделать в Sql Studio, правой кнопкой по базе, вкладка Options.

Comment: Опять, внесение изменений ничего не дало. Всё же думаю, что прблема в php7, либо версии Symfony